# How to initialize 2-d array as class variable?

Tags: c++

I have a class definition as such:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

#define MAX_ROW 10
#define MAX_COLUMN 40

class VideoSim
{

private:
    char video[MAX_ROW][MAX_COLUMN];
    int currentRow;
    int currentColumn;


public:
    VideoSim::VideoSim(void);
    VideoSim::~VideoSim(void);
    void clearScreen(void);
    int setCursorPosition(int row, int column);


};
```

I also have my .cpp file that contains these methods as such:

```
#include "VideoSim.h"



VideoSim::VideoSim(void)
{

    currentRow = 0;
    currentColumn = 0;
    video[MAX_ROW][MAX_COLUMN] = { 0 };

}

VideoSim::~VideoSim(void)
{
    printf("Dead Video \n");
}

void VideoSim::clearScreen(void)
{

    int count = 0;
    char *pVideo = video[count];

    for (count = 0; count < (MAX_ROW * MAX_COLUMN); count++)
    {
        *(pVideo++) = ' ';
    }

}



int VideoSim::setCursorPosition(int newRow, int newColumn)
{
    if (newRow >= 0 && newRow <= MAX_ROW && newColumn >= 0 && newColumn <= MAX_COLUMN)
    {
        currentColumn = newColumn;
        currentRow = newRow;
        return 0;

    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }


}
```

Now this is where the problem is occurring in my main:

```
#include "VideoSim.h"



int main(void)
{

    VideoSim v;
    return 0;
}
```

The program creates the VideoSim Object named `v` but then crashes... any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Consider `std::array` for arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to initialize all elements to 0 in your array you have to use initializer syntax:

```
VideoSim::VideoSim()
    : video{}
{
    currentRow = 0;
    currentColumn = 0;
}
```

In the line `video[MAX_ROW][MAX_COLUMN] = { 0 };` you write a zero to `video[MAX_ROW][MAX_COLUMN]` which is an out of bounds error.

You can also put the zero initialization in the class definition as:

```
    char video[MAX_ROW][MAX_COLUMN]{};
```

If you eventually add custom constructors you can then just overwrite this default initialization by providing a different initialization like the one in the constructor above.

Comment: Okay, my mistake.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using this solution as opposed to using:
memset(video,0, sizeof(video));
In my constructor?

Comment: Yes, this is more explicit, doesn't use a low level function and can be faster as you don't call any function. And also the compiler can optimize the zero initialization as it is the default initialization for build in types.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

```
char video[MAX_ROW][MAX_COLUMN] = {{0}};//initialize all elements to NULL
```

Comment: why would i have to add the char in front if it is already declared that way inside my class definition?

Comment: Oh i see, sorry i can't remember why but i was taught not to initialize any data within my class definition and only in my constructor.

Comment: Makes no difference. And in your code you are not initializing it. It is not initialized at all and then you assign values to your variables. To initialize your values I would recommend initializer syntax. (`someval{0}`)

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoSim::VideoSim(void)
{

    currentRow = 0;
    currentColumn = 0;
    memset(video,0, sizeof(video));

}
```